# UiPath -Error {"message":"Click Text 'SAPTreeList': Cannot find the UI element corresponding to this selector: <wnd ctrlid='90279688' />

Tags: uipath, sap-erp, sap-gui, uipath-studio

I am following the video [SAP Automation with UiPath](https://www.uipath.com/developers/video-tutorials/sap-automation) to automate login as a user with valid credentials within a SAP Server.

> **SAP Information**: IDES ECC 6.0 incl. EhP7
>
> **System Information**: I am not using a VM. I use a `Intel Core i3 CPU` with `64 bit - Windows 8` system.

The login process as per the tutorial basically works for an hour or so since it's creation. But whenever I am trying to execute the *workflow* after long intervals (example, next day), the robot won't start and I am facing an error as:

Studio.log:

```
13:12:54.1664 => [ERROR] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [7] $LoadAssembly: UiPath.Vision, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.4.1.2984, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.4.1.2984, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Execution.log:

```
13:16:44.2967 Error {"message":"Click Text 'SAPTreeList': Cannot find the UI element corresponding to this selector: <wnd ctrlid='90279688' /><wnd ctrlid='100' title='SAP&apos;s Advanced Treelist' />","level":"Error","logType":"Default","timeStamp":"2019-02-06T13:16:44.295729+05:30","fingerprint":"bec67d2a-14d1-4b93-ac06-03156aea69fe","windowsIdentity":"AtechM-03\\AtechM_03","machineName":"ATECHM-03","processName":"LearningUiPath","processVersion":"1.0.0.0","jobId":"e7f88d9e-e485-4eee-8a54-7450771238f3","robotName":"ATECHM_03","machineId":0,"fileName":"Main"}
```

Snapshot of the WorkFlow:

[image: SAP_workflow]

Complete Studio.log:

```html
13:12:31.1048 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [1] Set native thread language to LangId=0x0009
13:12:31.4221 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.Shared.MVVM.Commands.CommandManager] [1] Application.MainWindow is null, cannot subscribe to keyboard events, subscribed to Application.Activated event
13:12:37.2585 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [8] GetRobotConnectionStatus took 2971 ms.
13:12:39.0493 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [1] IUpdateManager: Starting automatic update
13:12:39.0762 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [1] CheckForUpdateImpl: Using existing staging user ID: b66eca10-67ef-5ddd-bf27-bde6f41925ba
13:12:39.1003 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [1] CheckForUpdateImpl: Downloading RELEASES file from http://download.uipath.com/latest?timestamp=636850555590282764
13:12:39.1003 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [1] FileDownloader: Downloading url: http://download.uipath.com/latest/RELEASES?timestamp=636850555590282764&id=UiPath&localVersion=19.1.0&arch=amd64
13:12:43.1631 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [5] Installing packages: UiPath.UIAutomation.Activities, UiPath.System.Activities, UiPath.Excel.Activities, UiPath.Mail.Activities
13:12:43.8417 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.Shared.Logging.OutputLogger] [5] Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: C:\Users\AtechM_03\Documents\UiPath\LearningUiPath\.local\AllDependencies.json
13:12:44.1160 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\avalonedit/5.0.3\lib/Net40/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.dll
13:12:44.2121 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\caliburn.micro/3.0.1\lib/net45/Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Core.dll
13:12:44.2121 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\caliburn.micro/3.0.1\lib/net45/Caliburn.Micro.Platform.dll
13:12:44.2121 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\caliburn.micro/3.0.1\lib/net45/System.Windows.Interactivity.dll
13:12:44.2121 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\caliburn.micro.core/3.0.1\lib/net45/Caliburn.Micro.dll
13:12:44.2121 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\extended.wpf.toolkit/2.8.0\lib/net40/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll
13:12:44.2411 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\extended.wpf.toolkit/2.8.0\lib/net40/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.Aero.dll
13:12:44.2571 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\extended.wpf.toolkit/2.8.0\lib/net40/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.Metro.dll
13:12:44.2711 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\extended.wpf.toolkit/2.8.0\lib/net40/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.VS2010.dll
13:12:44.2711 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\extended.wpf.toolkit/2.8.0\lib/net40/Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.dll
13:12:44.3542 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\extended.wpf.toolkit/2.8.0\lib/net40/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll
13:12:44.3803 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\humanizer.core/2.4.2\lib/netstandard2.0/Humanizer.dll
13:12:44.3803 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath/10.0.6913.22031\lib/UiPath.Interop.dll
13:12:44.3803 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Docking.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.3963 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Editors.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.3963 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Ribbon.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.3963 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Shared.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.3963 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.SyntaxEditor.Addons.DotNet.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.3963 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.SyntaxEditor.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.3963 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Text.Addons.DotNet.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.3963 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Text.LLParser.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.3963 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Text.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.3963 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Wizard.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.4143 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/UiPath.UIAutomation.Activities.Design.dll
13:12:44.4143 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/UiPath.UiAutomation.Activities.dll
13:12:44.4143 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.uiautomation.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/UiPath.Wizards.dll
13:12:44.4143 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.vision/1.2.0\lib/net452/UiPath.NeuralNet.dll
13:12:44.4143 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.vision/1.2.0\lib/net452/UiPath.Vision.Core.dll
13:12:44.4143 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.vision/1.2.0\lib/net452/UiPath.Vision.dll
13:12:44.4143 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.vision/1.2.0\lib/net452/UiPath.Vision.Package.dll
13:12:44.4143 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\csvhelper/2.13.5\lib/net40-client/CsvHelper.dll
13:12:44.4143 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\microsoft.rest.clientruntime/2.3.10\lib/net452/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json/10.0.3\lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Docking.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Ribbon.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Shared.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.SyntaxEditor.Addons.DotNet.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.SyntaxEditor.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Text.Addons.DotNet.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Text.LLParser.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Text.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/ActiproSoftware.Wizard.Wpf.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/UiPath.OrchestratorClient.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/UiPath.System.Activities.Design.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.system.activities/18.4.1\lib/net461/UiPath.System.Activities.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\closedxml/0.87.1\lib/net40/ClosedXML.dll
13:12:44.4273 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\documentformat.openxml/2.5.0\lib/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll
13:12:44.4493 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop/7.10.6071\lib/Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll
13:12:44.4493 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\npoi/2.2.1\lib/net40/NPOI.dll
13:12:44.4493 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\npoi/2.2.1\lib/net40/NPOI.OOXML.dll
13:12:44.4493 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\npoi/2.2.1\lib/net40/NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll
13:12:44.4583 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\npoi/2.2.1\lib/net40/NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.dll
13:12:44.4583 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\sharpziplib/0.86.0\lib/20/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll
13:12:44.4583 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.excel.activities/2.4.6884.25683\lib/net452/UiPath.Excel.Activities.Design.dll
13:12:44.4583 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.excel.activities/2.4.6884.25683\lib/net452/UiPath.Excel.Activities.dll
13:12:44.4583 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.excel.activities/2.4.6884.25683\lib/net452/UiPath.Excel.dll
13:12:44.4583 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\bouncycastle/1.8.1\lib/BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll
13:12:44.4583 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\microsoft.exchange.webservices/2.2.0\lib/40/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.dll
13:12:44.4583 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\microsoft.exchange.webservices/2.2.0\lib/40/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
13:12:44.4583 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.mail.activities/1.2.6863.29868\lib/net40/MailKit.dll
13:12:44.4744 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.mail.activities/1.2.6863.29868\lib/net40/MimeKit.dll
13:12:44.4744 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.mail.activities/1.2.6863.29868\lib/net40/UiPath.Mail.Activities.Design.dll
13:12:44.4744 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.mail.activities/1.2.6863.29868\lib/net40/UiPath.Mail.Activities.dll
13:12:44.4744 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [17] TryLoadAssemblyInternal: Loading C:\Users\AtechM_03\.nuget\packages\uipath.mail.activities/1.2.6863.29868\lib/net40/UiPath.Mail.dll
13:12:49.8033 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Found activities assembly: UiPath.UIAutomation.Activities.Design, Version=18.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
13:12:49.8033 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Found activities assembly: UiPath.UiAutomation.Activities, Version=18.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
13:12:49.8033 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Found activities assembly: UiPath.Wizards, Version=18.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
13:12:49.8033 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Found activities assembly: UiPath.System.Activities.Design, Version=18.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
13:12:49.8033 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Found activities assembly: UiPath.System.Activities, Version=18.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
13:12:49.8033 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Found activities assembly: UiPath.Excel.Activities.Design, Version=2.4.6884.25683, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
13:12:49.8033 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Found activities assembly: UiPath.Excel.Activities, Version=2.4.6884.25679, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
13:12:49.8033 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Found activities assembly: UiPath.Mail.Activities.Design, Version=1.2.6863.29868, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
13:12:49.8414 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Found activities assembly: UiPath.Mail.Activities, Version=1.2.6863.29861, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
13:12:49.8414 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Registering contract: UiPath.Core.Activities.Design.DesignerMetadata
13:12:50.1647 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Registering contract: UiPath.Core.Activities.Design.DesignerMetadata
13:12:50.7442 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Registering contract: UiPath.Excel.Activities.Design.DesignerMetadata
13:12:50.8833 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [4] Registering contract: UiPath.Mail.Activities.Design.DesignerMetadata
13:12:54.1664 => [ERROR] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [7] $LoadAssembly: UiPath.Vision, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.4.1.2984, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.4.1.2984, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.get_Signature()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.get_PropertyType()
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.BinaryAssemblyLoader.#aFc(#Lrc #wAf, MemberInfo #xAf)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.BinaryAssemblyLoader.#cFc(#hsc #4Ub, Type #uAf)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.BinaryAssemblyLoader.#XEc(Assembly #sxc)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.#30j(Assembly #sxc, IAssemblyName #4tc, IBinaryAssemblyMetadata #RDb)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.Create(Assembly assembly, IAssemblyName assemblyName, IBinaryAssemblyMetadata metadata)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.FileBasedAssemblyRepository.Create(Assembly assembly, IAssemblyName assemblyName, IBinaryAssemblyMetadata metadata)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.FileBasedAssemblyRepository.GetOrCreate(Assembly assembly, IAssemblyName assemblyName, String location)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.#uBh(Assembly #sxc, IAssemblyName #4tc, String #bVe)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.Load(Assembly assembly, IAssemblyName assemblyName)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.Load(String fullName)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Workflow.ExpressionEditor.SyntaxService.LoadAssembly(LoadIntellisenseAssembliesContext context, String assemblyName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
, HResult -2147024894
13:12:54.2836 => [ERROR] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [7] $LoadAssembly: UiPath.NeuralNet, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.4.1.2984, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.4.1.2984, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.get_Signature()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.get_PropertyType()
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.BinaryAssemblyLoader.#aFc(#Lrc #wAf, MemberInfo #xAf)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.BinaryAssemblyLoader.#cFc(#hsc #4Ub, Type #uAf)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.BinaryAssemblyLoader.#XEc(Assembly #sxc)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.BinaryAssemblyLoader.#iFc(Assembly #sxc)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.#30j(Assembly #sxc, IAssemblyName #4tc, IBinaryAssemblyMetadata #RDb)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.Create(Assembly assembly, IAssemblyName assemblyName, IBinaryAssemblyMetadata metadata)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.FileBasedAssemblyRepository.Create(Assembly assembly, IAssemblyName assemblyName, IBinaryAssemblyMetadata metadata)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.FileBasedAssemblyRepository.GetOrCreate(Assembly assembly, IAssemblyName assemblyName, String location)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.#uBh(Assembly #sxc, IAssemblyName #4tc, String #bVe)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.Load(Assembly assembly, IAssemblyName assemblyName)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.Load(String fullName)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Workflow.ExpressionEditor.SyntaxService.LoadAssembly(LoadIntellisenseAssembliesContext context, String assemblyName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
, HResult -2147024894
13:12:54.3206 => [ERROR] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [7] $LoadAssembly: UiPath.Vision, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.4.1.2984, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.4.1.2984, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.get_Signature()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.get_PropertyType()
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.BinaryAssemblyLoader.#aFc(#Lrc #wAf, MemberInfo #xAf)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.FileBasedAssemblyRepository.GetOrCreate(Assembly assembly, IAssemblyName assemblyName, String location)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.#uBh(Assembly #sxc, IAssemblyName #4tc, String #bVe)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.Load(Assembly assembly, IAssemblyName assemblyName)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.Load(String fullName)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Workflow.ExpressionEditor.SyntaxService.LoadAssembly(LoadIntellisenseAssembliesContext context, String assemblyName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
, HResult -2147024894
13:12:55.8830 => [INFO] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [1] Entry Point: C:\Users\AtechM_03\Documents\UiPath\LearningUiPath\Main.xaml
13:12:56.1233 => [ERROR] [UiPath.Studio.exe] [7] $LoadAssembly: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.get_Signature()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.get_PropertyType()
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.BinaryAssemblyLoader.#aFc(#Lrc #wAf, MemberInfo #xAf)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.BinaryAssemblyLoader.#cFc(#hsc #4Ub, Type #uAf)
   at ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.AssemblyRepositoryBase.#30j(Assembly #sxc, IAssemblyName #4tc, IBinaryAssemblyMetadata #RDb)
   at  ActiproSoftware.Text.Languages.DotNet.Reflection.Implementation.FileBasedAssemblyRepository.GetOrCreate(Assembly assembly, IAssemblyName assemblyName, String location)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
, HResult -2147024894
```

Complete Execution.log:

```html
13:16:13.6158 Info {"message":"LearningUiPath execution started","level":"Information","logType":"Default","timeStamp":"2019-02-06T13:16:13.5988758+05:30","fingerprint":"214b3d1f-302f-44b5-82ba-1a5eccded1bb","windowsIdentity":"AtechM-03\\AtechM_03","machineName":"ATECHM-03","processName":"LearningUiPath","processVersion":"1.0.0.0","jobId":"e7f88d9e-e485-4eee-8a54-7450771238f3","robotName":"ATECHM_03","machineId":0,"fileName":"Main"}
13:16:44.2967 Error {"message":"Click Text 'SAPTreeList': Cannot find the UI element corresponding to this selector: <wnd ctrlid='90279688' /><wnd ctrlid='100' title='SAP&apos;s Advanced Treelist' />","level":"Error","logType":"Default","timeStamp":"2019-02-06T13:16:44.295729+05:30","fingerprint":"bec67d2a-14d1-4b93-ac06-03156aea69fe","windowsIdentity":"AtechM-03\\AtechM_03","machineName":"ATECHM-03","processName":"LearningUiPath","processVersion":"1.0.0.0","jobId":"e7f88d9e-e485-4eee-8a54-7450771238f3","robotName":"ATECHM_03","machineId":0,"fileName":"Main"}
13:16:44.3057 Info {"message":"LearningUiPath execution ended","level":"Information","logType":"Default","timeStamp":"2019-02-06T13:16:44.3017318+05:30","fingerprint":"22bd0086-d076-42eb-b8d7-9bf13c3fb815","windowsIdentity":"AtechM-03\\AtechM_03","machineName":"ATECHM-03","processName":"LearningUiPath","processVersion":"1.0.0.0","jobId":"e7f88d9e-e485-4eee-8a54-7450771238f3","robotName":"ATECHM_03","machineId":0,"totalExecutionTimeInSeconds":30,"totalExecutionTime":"00:00:30","fileName":"Main"}
```

Any pointers where I am going wrong?

---

### Update

While working with @NTP's answer got to the bottom of the issue. Need to construct a locator (non-expiring) from the following:

[image: SAP_SAP's Advanced Treelist_debugger]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message

```
Cannot find the UI element corresponding to this selector: <wnd ctrlid='90279688' /><wnd ctrlid='100' title='SAP&apos;s Advanced Treelist' />”
```

Says UI path cannot find your element.

I can think of 2 possible causes for this problem.

1. Selector Issues for which you can do the following

   - Use partial selectors instead of full selectors
   - Use wildcards for dynamic parts of your selectors (* for replacing any number of
     characters, ? for replacing exactly 1 character)
2. Something happens to your SAP application / application closes for some reason for which you can try the following

   - You should consider adding some error handling logic to recover from these errors instead of crashing and terminating the whole workflow.For this you can use Try Catch activity of UI path https://activities.uipath.com/docs/try-catch.  You can recover from this error simply by closing and reopening your SAP application. You can add a workflow in catch block to do this action if you decide to go with error handling.

Summary of the points discussed in comments:

- Use highlight feature of the UI path to help with debugging of the selectors.
- Desktop recording of UI path generates partial selectors where as basic recording generates full selectors.
- Anchor base activity of UI path can be used when a reliable selector is not available. https://activities.uipath.com/docs/anchor-base

Comment: Your solution was an eye-opener with respect to this issue. I have a couple of counter questions: My current selector captured by the robot is `"<wnd app='saplogon.exe' cls='#32770' title='SAP Logon 750' />"`. So what can be a good partial selector to use?

Comment: I'm glad I could help, is there any text that changes in title string?

Comment: Well, no, the title won't change.

Comment: looking at your question again looks like the problematic part is this selector <wnd ctrlid='100' title='SAP&apos;s Advanced Treelist' />

Comment: You can use highlight feature of UI path to highlight elements corresponding to a given selector to help with debugging

Comment: Actually, after going through your answer I tried to gather information about the parameters _ctrlid_, _fingerprint_, etc. yet to come to a conclusion.

Comment: Well, seems the issue is not related to the element identified as `"<wnd app='saplogon.exe' cls='#32770' title='SAP Logon 750' />"` atall but the issue is related to the next element `Display Name : Click Text 'SAPTreeList'` Any other hints/pointers?

Comment: I believe I also mentioned that the problem is related to SAPTreeList selector, I wish I could help further but it is hard to debug selectors without having the code. What you can do is to use highlight feature as I mentioned in previous comment and follow the steps in answer.

Comment: Just did that as you mentioned. Not sure exactly which attribute can expire, `<wnd app='saplogon.exe' cls='#32770' title='SAP Logon 750' />`, `<wnd ctrlid='74372104' />`, `<wnd ctrlid='5002' title='myContainer' />` or `<wnd ctrlid='1008' />`. Should I be using all the 4 selectors at the same time or I can choose any one of them or may club up 2 of them?

Comment: Currently what you have is a full selector, which means your selector contains all the elements needed to locate your UI element. It is better to use a partial selector.

Comment: Sounds great, so can you suggest me an ideal locator in this case please?

Comment: I think the fastest solution for you would be to use desktop recording feature of UI path. Desktop recording generates partial selectors. You can use desktop recording to capture your elements and compare the selector generated with your current ones. Also keep in mind that basic recorder generates full selectors.

Comment: Yeah, it was a `desktop recording` only

Comment: @DebanjanB I do not know how your UI is but if it is hard to find a proper selector you can also use anchor base activity of UI path. https://activities.uipath.com/docs/anchor-base

Comment: Okay, all your words had been of eminent help. Now, I have zeroed down on the main element causing the trouble which I have updated within the main question. My final question would be: Since I am using a `ClickText` event, the properties shown by UiPath are: 1) _Display Name_ as `Click Text 'SAPTreeList'`, 2) _Click Type_ as `CLICK_SINGLE`, 3) _MouseButton_ as `BTN_LEFT`, 3) _Text_ as `"Connections"`. So how do I accomodate a locator e.g. `<wnd ctrlid='5002' title='myContainer' />`

Comment: @DebanjanB check out the previous comment related to the anchor-base activity. I think It will make your life a lot more easier.