# How to construct a selector based on dynamic ctrlid through UiPath?

Tags: windows, uipath, sap-erp, sap-gui, uipath-studio

This question have a reference to the following questions:

- [UiPath -Error {“message”:"Click Text 'SAPTreeList': Cannot find the UI element corresponding to this selector:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549466/uipath-error-messageclick-text-saptreelist-cannot-find-the-ui-element-c)
- [Why does the ctrlid format detected by UiPath differs from the documented format in their XSLT representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789304/why-does-the-ctrlid-format-detected-by-uipath-differs-from-the-documented-format)

I am following the video [SAP Automation with UiPath](https://www.uipath.com/developers/video-tutorials/sap-automation) to automate logging in through a SAP client as a user with valid credentials.

Environment Details:

- > SAP Client: IDES ECC 6.0 incl. EhP7
- > Host machine: Intel Core i3 CPU with 64 bit - Windows 8 system.

Following the video I have a `Attach Window` activity which contains two activities as follows:

- A `Click Text` of ClickType as `CLICK_SINGLE`
- A `Click Text` of ClickType as `CLICK_DOUBLE`

The elements as identified by *Selector Editor* or *UI Explorer* are as follows:

```
<wnd ctrlid='76836616' />
<wnd ctrlid='100' title='SAP&apos;s Advanced Treelist' />
```

and

```
<wnd ctrlid='76836616' />
<wnd ctrlid='5002' title='myContainer' />
<wnd ctrlid='1008' />
<ctrl name='SAP_IDES' role='list item' />
```

As you can observe the **`ctrlid`** is same for both the elements but some how it is dynamic. However, the first couple of executions are perfecto.

The issue starts when trying to execute the workflow after a considerable amount of time have elapsed. I was facing an error as:

```
Error {"message":"Click Text 'SAPTreeList': Cannot find the UI element corresponding to this selector: <wnd ctrlid='90279688' /><wnd ctrlid='100' title='SAP&apos;s Advanced Treelist' />","level":"Error","logType":"Default","timeStamp":"2019-02-06T13:16:44.295729+05:30","fingerprint":"bec67d2a-14d1-4b93-ac06-03156aea69fe","windowsIdentity":"AtechM-03\\AtechM_03","machineName":"ATECHM-03","processName":"LearningUiPath","processVersion":"1.0.0.0","jobId":"e7f88d9e-e485-4eee-8a54-7450771238f3","robotName":"ATECHM_03","machineId":0,"fileName":"Main"}
```

So it was clear from the error message that the `selector` wasn't a valid selector.

Using *Selector Editor* and *UI Explorer* I found the **`ctrlid`** changes from **`'76836616'`** to **`'79865432'`**. So I tried to use *partial selector*. It is observed that *UiPath* randomly:

- Identifies the element omitting `<wnd ctrlid='76836616' />` but on execution shows error as:

  ```
  Error {"message":"Click Text 'SAPTreeList': Cannot find the UI element corresponding to this selector: <wnd omit:ctrlid='76836616' /><wnd ctrlid='100' title='SAP&apos;s Advanced Treelist' />","level":"Error","logType":"Default","timeStamp":"2019-02-27T11:59:39.2811258+05:30","fingerprint":"752fe27b-16f4-4e7b-95c0-f1e8a6b49e7b","windowsIdentity":"AtechM-03\\AtechM_03","machineName":"ATECHM-03","processName":"LearningUiPath","processVersion":"1.0.0.0","jobId":"b6ba7310-749c-4c28-a9d3-d1db0c6c7dec","robotName":"ATECHM_03","machineId":0,"fileName":"SAP_UserList_BOT"}
  ```
- Identifies the element with *wildcards* in *partial selector* as `<wnd ctrlid='7*' />`. This works for 4-5 rounds of execution. But then **`'76836616'`** also changes to **`'88068312'`** where the execution fails.

So my question is how do I accomodate the *dynamic `ctrlid`* which changes time to time and is a mandatory selector for UiPath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UI path has an [anchor base activity](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/anchor-base) that you can use when there is no reliable selector. It is a container for an anchor and an action acitivty that tries to locate your UI element by using other UI elements as anchors. You can you use both **find element** and **find image** activities as anchors.

For example you can use a label for an input as anchor for your input as it is less likely for label to change.

Keep in mind that anchor base acitivity **does not work** in the **background**.

You can test efficiency / reliability  of anchor base activity by trying to complete the challenge in this page. http://www.rpachallenge.com/ As in your case name and id attributes of inputs on rpachallenge page also changes on every submit.